# Java Beginning Scanner

Tags: java, string

I am a novice programmer and I am trying to do projects that I find fun to help me learn more about the language then my school classes have been able to provide.  I have wanted to try reversing a string but instead of having the string defined in a string I have added a scanner to be able to allow a user to input what they want.  After searching for any help I haven't been able to find my issue that I am having.  So far I have this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Reverse {

    static ArrayList<String> newString = new ArrayList();

    static int inputLength = 0;
    static String PlaceHolder = null;
    static String beReturned = null;
    static int lengthArray = 0;
    static String ToBeReversed;
    static String hold = null;

    public static void reversal(){
            inputLength = ToBeReversed.length();
        for (int e = 0; e <= inputLength; e++)
        {
                PlaceHolder = ToBeReversed.substring(inputLength -1, inputLength);
                newString.add(PlaceHolder);         
        }

    }

    public static String putTogether()
    {
        int lengthcounter = 0;

        lengthArray = newString.size();
        for (int i = 0; i <  lengthArray; i++)
        {
            beReturned = beReturned + newString.get(lengthcounter);
            if (lengthcounter < lengthArray)
            {
            lengthcounter++;
            }
        }
            return beReturned;
        }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //create a new scanner 

        ToBeReversed = input.nextLine();
        Reverse.reversal();
        Reverse.putTogether();

        }

}
```

For any input that I input there is no result.  I don't get an Error Message or any form of return... The output is blank.  I am just wondering if I made a mistake with the scanner or if it is how I am trying to store the characters/access them from the ArrayList I created.  I am trying to not have others give me the answer completely with all the fixes, I hope I can just get a pointer or a hint to where I am messing up.   Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Where are you printing the string? how do you know that there is no result?

Comment: You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

Comment: @RJadhav I am using Eclipse to do my coding and compiling.  I have the Eclipse console open and it allows me to type in what I want due to the scanner and when I press enter the output should appear underneath what I typed because of the return statement in my putTogether method.

Comment: You need to print the output, for example `System.out.println(Reverse.putTogether());` for example...

Comment: @MadProgrammer   Thank you a ton.  I will read over the conventions as I should learn to do them now before I develop bad habits.

Comment: +1 for a great question, for making attempts and just for been willing to have a go at some "stuff", this is how you become a great coder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to print the output, for example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //create a new scanner 

    ToBeReversed = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("ToBeReversed = " + ToBeReversed);
    Reverse.reversal();
    System.out.println("newString = " + newString);
    System.out.println(Reverse.putTogether());

}
```

I don't want to give a complete answer, as that would spoil your fun (and steal an opportunity for your to get started with using a debugger), but here are some hints...

- You can use `String#charAt` to get an individual character from a `String` at a given index
- Java is generally 0 indexed, that means that things like arrays, `String`, `List` start at index `0` and go through to `length - 1`
- `null` + `String` = `nullString` ;)
- You can run a loop backwards.  `for-loop` doesn't have to run from `0-x` in ascending order, they can run `x-0` in descending order ;)

Comment: I want to clarify something quickly about the System.out.println().  You referenced my putTogether method inside of the println.  Is this possible because I have it return a string so it is able to print that out?

Comment: @MichaelShoenberger it is possible because your method returns something (it is not declared as `void`).

Comment: `putTogether` returns `String`, so it would the same as assigning the return value to a `String` variable and printing it

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ah ok so it is because it isn't a void method so it is able to return and as such println can print out what a method returns.  You have been an extreme help and I can't thank you enough.  I have learned some more things of how the language works and this knowledge will be able to aid me from here on out.

Comment: @MichaelShoenberger You might find [The Java Trails](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) a useful resource

Comment: @MadProgrammer  I thank you for all of the resources and hints you have given me.  I am going to use these to help me expand my knowledge and try applying it.  If I have any other questions I will create a new question after checking to see if there are any answers already.  :)

Comment: @MichaelShoenberger You're at the beginning of a really awesome and fun adventure!  Never be afraid to try something and if it goes wrong, do some research, if that fails, post you attempt, we're always willing to help those who try ;)